# Python list for each 4 in the list from right

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python, eg. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

I want to make a new list with only the 4. element from the right? .. how to do that, eg. with a one liner.

eq. to .. [4,8,12]

Comment: like this: a = [b[3]]

Comment: You mean, each 4th element? Like this `my_list[3::4]`?

Comment: @bereal - they say from the right. Depending on number of elements it may not start at 3

Comment: @buran good point.

Comment: arhh .. rather : my_list[::4] .. thanks.

Comment: @pkdkk that will return `[1, 5, 9]`.

Comment: Humm, not what i expected.. my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]. i need a list to be [2, 6,10,14]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply like so in one line: (where a is your list)

```
print(a[-1::-4][::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
print(foo[-1::-4])
```

output

```
[12, 8, 4]
```

reverse it, if the order is important